# How to get tab by child element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

With jQuery UI tabs, is there a way to get tab index by a child element?

Example:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Second</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
        <input type="text" id="name">
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <input type="text" id="age">
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
```

How to get the index of tab where element $("#age") is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might help you:

```
$(function() {
    var parentId,tabIndex;

    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

    parentId = $("#age").parents("div[id*='tabs']").attr("id");
    tabIndex = $("li a[href='#"+parentId+"']").parents("li").index();

    console.log("#age : "+ tabIndex);
});
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lxnyh1e/2/).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent of an element by using the 'closest' method:

```
var currentTab = $('#age').closest('div');
```

Comment: This won't give you the "index of tab where element X is" as requested,